# 'Workflow' cloud not be added to Xcode Cloud, request is rated limited/you must have 'Admin' permission

Tags: ios, xcode, workflow, xcode-cloud

When I try to create a workflow in Xcode I get this error message sometimes:

```
"WORKFLOW_NAME" could not be added to Xcode Cloud, request is rated limited
```

However, sometimes I get this one:

```
""WORKFLOW_NAME" could not be added to Xcode Cloud, you must have 'Admin' permissions to the repository
```

I already have admin permissions to the repository and it hasn't been used for more than 25 hours this month so I don't understand what's going on.
On the other hand Apple support for a change, is unable to give me a coherent answer, so any help would be appreciated.

This is not the first workflow I have created as my application is distributed to several people but the assets change, I have followed the normal workflow creation process, as I had done with the previous ones and as shown in the documentation.